# Bit Array to String and back to Bit Array

Tags: c#, string, arrays, bitarray, huffman-code

Possible Duplicate [Converting byte array to string and back again in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422314/converting-byte-array-to-string-and-back-again-in-c-sharp)

I am using Huffman Coding for compression and decompression of some text from [here](http://snipd.net/huffman-coding-in-c)

The code in there builds a huffman tree to use it for encoding and decoding. Everything **works fine when I use the code directly**.

For my situation, i need to get the compressed content, store it and decompress it when ever need.

The output from the encoder and the input to the decoder are `BitArray`.

When I tried convert this `BitArray` to `String` and back to `BitArray` and decode it using the following code, I get a weird answer.

```
Tree huffmanTree = new Tree();
huffmanTree.Build(input);

string input = Console.ReadLine();
BitArray encoded = huffmanTree.Encode(input);

// Print the bits
Console.Write("Encoded Bits: ");
foreach (bool bit in encoded)
{
    Console.Write((bit ? 1 : 0) + "");
}
Console.WriteLine();

// Convert the bit array to bytes
Byte[] e = new Byte[(encoded.Length / 8 + (encoded.Length % 8 == 0 ? 0 : 1))];
encoded.CopyTo(e, 0);

// Convert the bytes to string
string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e);

// Convert string back to bytes
e = new Byte[d.Length];
e = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(d);

// Convert bytes back to bit array
BitArray todecode = new BitArray(e);

string decoded = huffmanTree.Decode(todecode);

Console.WriteLine("Decoded: " + decoded);

Console.ReadLine();
```

The Output of Original code from [the tutorial](http://snipd.net/huffman-coding-in-c) is:

[image]

The Output of My Code is:

[image]

Where am I wrong friends? Help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that C# strings are UTF-16.

Comment: I tried ASCII with same weird answer. I tried Unicode (UTF-16) but give half right and half junk answer. Like `Welcome` gives `WelcomESTT`

Comment: The issue is that `CopyTo` assumes LSB-first, whereas everyone other sane API in the world uses MSB-first.  Thus `10000000b` is equal to `1` instead of `128`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot stuff arbitrary bytes into a string. That concept is just undefined. Conversions happen using Encoding.

```
string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e);
```

`e` is just binary garbage at this point, it is *not* a UTF8 string. So calling UTF8 methods on it does not make sense.

Solution: Don't convert and back-convert to/from string. This does not round-trip. Why are you doing that in the first place? If you *need* a string use a round-trippable format like base-64 or base-85.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Encoding doesn't roundtrip - that is you can't encode an arbitrary sequence of bytes to a string, and then use the same Encoding to get bytes back and *always* expect them to be the same.

If you want to be able to roundtrip from your raw bytes to string and back to the same raw bytes, you'd need to use base64 encoding e.g.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/mneiter/archive/2009/03/22/how-to-encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-c.aspx

Comment: But base64 gives 4/3 of the input instead of compressing it. I need compression not encoding(SRC: wikipedia.org)

Comment: @GopikrishnaS Then you need to use `byte[]`, not `string`. `string` is for character data, not binary.